# What new peer services do segregated witness nodes need to implement?

Tags: segregated-witness

What new peer services do segregated witness nodes need to implement? In particular, if you want a node to relay both a block and its witness data, how do you request that?

Comment: Have you seen the [Segregated Witness Wallet Development Guide](https://bitcoincore.org/en/segwit_wallet_dev/)? It provides an overview about working with SegWit.